# How to do a qwery witch filter ActiveRecord::Relation by linked relation number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have to tables in my Rails app which are linked by a **ActiveRecord::Relation** like so.

```
# Table name: lease_rents
#  id                  :bigint not null, primary key
class LeaseRent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lease_tenant_payments,
  ...
end

class LeaseTenantPayment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lease_rent
  ...
end
```

each **LeaseRent** can have 0 or multiple **LeaseTenantPayment**.

in my **Rails console** i am trying to get only the **LeaseRent** witch have at least one or more **LeaseTenantPayment**.

to do so i have been able to get the number of **LeaseTenantPayment** linked to a specific **LeaseRent**

```
LeaseRent.all.where('id = 1').first.lease_tenant_payments.count
```

I want to get an **ActiveRecord::Relation** array whitch contain each **LeaseRent** witch have at least 1 or more **LeaseTenantPayment**. something like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<LeaseRent id: ...>,<LeaseRent id: ...>,<LeaseRent id: ...>,...]>
```

Does anyone have some idea of how to get it?

Comment: So in this relation I assume you have `lease_rent_id` in LeaseTenantPayment.
Now, you can probably just search for records of LTP with this is 
`LeaseTenantPayment.where.not(lease_rent_id: nil)`

Comment: yes, indeed i do have a lease_rent_id in LeaseTenantPayment. If i do like so i do get an array of LeaseTenantPayment.

like this: 
 ``` <ActiveRecord::Relation [#<LeaseTenantPayment  ...>,...]>```

but i want an array of LeaseRent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finaly got my solutions !

there are serval way to do it.

solution 1 :

```
LeaseRent.joins(:lease_tenant_payments).includes(:lease_tenant_payments)
```

solution 2 :

```
LeaseRent.joins(:lease_tenant_payments).distinct
```

solution 3 (my favorite cause it allow to revert it very easily juste by removing the '.not' ) :

```
LeaseRent.includes(:lease_tenant_payments).where.not(lease_tenant_payments: { id: nil })
```

i am using that way :

```
  scope "Aucun Paiement", :all, group: :unpayed do |rents|
    rents.includes(:lease_tenant_payments).where(lease_tenant_payments: { id: nil })
  end

  scope "Reliquat", :all, group: :unpayed do |rents|
    rents.includes(:lease_tenant_payments).where.not(lease_tenant_payments: { id: nil })
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a join, it would only return rows with `lease_tenant_payments`.

```rb
LeaseRent.joins(:lease_tenant_payments)
```

If you want to use them in a loop, you may need to also use `includes`

```rb
LeaseRent.joins(:lease_tenant_payments).includes(:lease_tenant_payments)
```

Comment: this one sems to work in the Rails console but in my app it is causing an infinite loop (i am using it in a scope in activeAdmin)

Comment: can you post the full code? maybe another question?

Comment: this on work just fine ! : 

scope "Aucun Paiement", :all, group: :unpayed do |rents|
    rents.includes(:lease_tenant_payments).where(lease_tenant_payments: { id: nil })
  end

  scope "Reliquat", :all, group: :unpayed do |rents|
    rents.includes(:lease_tenant_payments).where.not(lease_tenant_payments: { id: nil })
  end